# Core Data: Sorting & Decrypting Value from a Transformable Field

Tags: objective-c, ios, sorting, core-data, nsdata

I have some encrypted NSString store in a transformable field. I need to decrypt and list all value in alphabetical order.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
                                    initWithKey:@"trans_word" 
                                    ascending:YES
                                    comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSString* s1 = [encryptObj decryptingfromValue:obj1]; 
    NSString* s2 = [encryptObj decryptingfromValue:obj2]; 
    NSLog(@"xxx");
    return [s1 compare:s2];
}];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

It seems the block doesn't performance. Could you give me any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS and on OS X prior to 10.6 and when using SQLite-based stores, block predicates are not supported.

> **Special Considerations**
>
> In Mac OS X v10.6, Core Data supports this method in the in-memory and atomic stores, but not in the SQLite-based store. [(Link)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSPredicate/predicateWithBlock%3a)

Comment: Thanks you Alex! Is there any alternate method?

Comment: Not really. That's one of the problems with encrypting data. You can't do much with it. You could create a transient property (one that isn't saved to store) that contains the unencrypted data? I don't have much experience with the encryption stuff. :/

Comment: If you really must use block predicates, the only solution is to read them all into memory and use the block predicate sort on the array.